# include *.xacro in *.urdf

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I m trying to attach the intel realsense camera to my robot. My robot is in .urdf format and the camera is in *.urdf.xacro format. Is there any way to do this without converting either to another format?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402699/include-*.xacro-in-*.urdf/) by [Saurabh Rahatekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/56348/saurabh-rahatekar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2022-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yeah you can just copy the meat of the xacro into your urdf...its all the stuff in the `<xacro:macro>` section. alternatively, you can add a `<xacro:create>` tag at the end of the realsense file and then just `<include>` it in your urdf.

but you should really get comfortable with xacro. its great.

i feel your pain I had learn the xacro format while adding a _d415.urdf.xacro file too. but no. you don't need to make everything a macro and call it in a common file.

here is an example of making a common file to call all the macros I made

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="arlobot" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <!-- A common file to tie together all of the bits and bobs of the entire robot
  Modeled after turtlebot_description 
  NOTE: All Gazebo references are gone, so simulation will have to be rebuilt if you want it -->

  <!-- From $(find turtlebot_description)/urdf/common_properties.urdf.xacro -->
  <!-- It is required by asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro -->
  <xacro:property name="M_PI" value="3.1415926535897931"/>

  <!-- Include 3D camera -->
  <xacro:include filename="$(find realsense2_description)/urdf/_d415.urdf.xacro"/>

  <!-- Arlo -->
  <xacro:include filename="$(find arlo-description)/urdf/arlo_temp.urdf.xacro"/>

  <!-- RPLIDAR -->
  <!-- <xacro:include filename="$(find arlobot_ros)/urdf/asus_xtion_pro_chrisl8.urdf.xacro"/> -->

  <xacro:arlobot/>
  <xacro:stack_circles parent="base_link"/>
  <xacro:sensor_d415 parent="plate_0_link" use_nominal_extrinsics="true" add_plug="false" use_mesh="true">
    <origin xyz=".1945 0 .00475" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </xacro:sensor_d415>
</robot>
```

---

Originally posted by [dwd394](https://answers.ros.org/users/108750/dwd394/) with karma: 18 on 2022-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Saurabh Rahatekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/56348/saurabh-rahatekar/) on 2022-06-23**:
Hey, Thank you so much for the quick response. I will try this and get back to you if I run into any further errors.

**Comment by [Saurabh Rahatekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/56348/saurabh-rahatekar/) on 2022-06-23**:
I want to add this code to my urdf file.

**Comment by [dwd394](https://answers.ros.org/users/108750/dwd394/) on 2022-06-23**:
so i don't think the publish_pointcloud is a xacro arg for _d415.urdf.xacro ..... your arguments topic_ns and publish_pointcloud are wrong. open the _d415.urdf.xacro and the test_d415.urdf.xacro files in the realsense2_description package to get a better idea of what is going on. i believe you are mistaking the arguments as if they are in a launch file. all you are doing in URDF is specifying dimensions for the transforms. that's it.

the only arguments you can pass into a macro are ones that are explicitly called for in the macro.

**Comment by [Saurabh Rahatekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/56348/saurabh-rahatekar/) on 2022-06-23**:
But these are the contents of test_d435_camera.urdf.xacro this file and it is called in the launch file as well.
[launch file](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros/blob/development/realsense2_description/launch/view_d435_model.launch)

[urdf file](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros/blob/development/realsense2_description/urdf/test_d435_camera.urdf.xacro)

**Comment by [Saurabh Rahatekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/56348/saurabh-rahatekar/) on 2022-06-24**:
I converted my robot urdf into xacro and then included the camera xacro in it. It worked perfectly. I don't know why I was holding back on xacro. Thank you for recommending this path.

**Comment by [Saurabh Rahatekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/56348/saurabh-rahatekar/) on 2022-07-26**:
When I m launching the xacro from launch file, it is showing me some errors. But when I convert it to urdf using "xacro robot.urdf.xacro > model.urdf" and launch the urdf file using the same, it doesn't give me any error. Do you know why?

**Comment by [dwd394](https://answers.ros.org/users/108750/dwd394/) on 2022-07-26**:
i can't give any advice without knowing the error, but here is my launch file to display the urdf above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<launch>
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(find arlo-description)/urdf/test_arlo.urdf.xacro"/>

  <arg name="rviz_fixed_frame" default="base_link"/>
  
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"/>
  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher"/>

  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" required="true" args="-d $(find arlo-utilities)/config/rviz/arlo.rviz -f $(arg rviz_fixed_frame)"/>

</launch>
```

**Comment by [Saurabh Rahatekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/56348/saurabh-rahatekar/) on 2022-07-29**:
here is my launch file

```
<launch>
<arg name="model" default="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder'$(find robot_bringup)/urdf/model.urdf'"/>
<arg name="gui" default="true" />
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"/>
<param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find robot_bringup)/urdf/model.urdf" />
<node name="spawn_robot" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" respawn="false" args="-param robot_description -urdf -model fielderbot"/>
<node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find robot_bringup)/rviz/outdoor_ros.rviz" required="true" />
```